# TextView (With Scroll View) content has duplicate text during scroll after changing the Language from Settings

Tags: android, scroll, textview, duplicates

I am getting duplicate text in my textview while scrolling after changing the language of the device from Settings. If I click back and navigate to the same screen then it's working fine.

Please find below the code snippet.

```
  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
   </ScrollView>

   @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, final Bundle    
      avedInstanceState) {
         super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
         TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById  
            (R.id.description);
         description.setText(promoDescription); //promodescription is
         a string
    }
```

I am using OS 4.4.2 and Samsung Galaxy S4.

Comment: Can you link to an image?

Comment: yup link and also the code where you set it's text

Comment: I am not able to upload image here.

Comment: I solved this issue. Issue was with fragment. On language change fragment was added 2nd time which caused this issue.